# open cv exception error though my code is right

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <raspicam_cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace raspicam;

Mat frame;



void Setup ( int argc,char **argv, RaspiCam_Cv &Camera )
    {
     Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  ( "-w",argc,argv,400 ) );
     Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,  ( "-h",argc,argv,240 ) );
     Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, ( "-br",argc,argv,50 ) );
     Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_CONTRAST ,( "-co",argc,argv,50 ) );
     Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_SATURATION,  ( "-sa",argc,argv,50 ) );
     Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_GAIN,  ( "-g",argc,argv ,50 ) );
     Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FPS,  ( "-fps",argc,argv,100));
    }



int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
      RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
      Setup(argc, argv, Camera);
      cout<<"Connecting to camera"<<endl;
      if (!Camera.open())
           {

             cout<<"Failed to Connect"<<endl;
            }

            cout<<"Camera Id = "<<Camera.getId()<<endl;
         while(1)
          {
               auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
             Camera.grab();
             Camera.retrieve( frame);
            auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();


            std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;

           float t = elapsed_seconds.count();
            int FPS = 1/t;
           cout<<"FPS = "<<FPS<<endl;
imshow("orignal", frame);

waitKey(1);


}


return 0;
```

}
error:

---

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.1.2-pre) /home/pi/opencv/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:650: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

Aborted

Comment: .. when having [100+ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=opencv+The+function+is+not+implemented.+rebuild) about the same problem is not enough :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message exactly show what you should do. **Rebuild** OpenCV with GUI support!

Comment: What GUI backend did you select? Have you ever tried using stable release opencv(4.1.1)?

Comment: Yeah! I have tried with open CV version 4.1.2 and installed libgtk2.0-dev before installing it..and the problem resolved.